# How to handle media queries on landscape view

Tags: html, css, media-queries

Hello friends i have a website in which there are two headers , one header appears on mob view and other one appears on desktop view .I have used @media to hide and show the headers ,it works fine until i tilt my mobile.  when i tilt my mobile the hidden header pops out here's a piece of code i used.

```
 @media only screen and (max-width:767px)  {

.mobcat{
    display: none;

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could simple add `(orientation: landscape)` to your query like this

```
    @media only screen and (max-width:767px)  and (orientation: landscape)   
    {
    .mobcat{ 
          display: none;
           }
    }
```

or

```
 @media (max-width:767px) and (orientation: landscape) { 
        .mobcat{ 
              display: none;
               }
       }
```

Comment: Definition and Usage
The @media rule is used in media queries to apply different styles for different media types/devices.

Media queries can be used to check many things, such as:

width and height of the viewport
width and height of the device
orientation (is the tablet/phone in landscape or portrait mode?)
resolution

Comment: So what do you really wants to achieve??